# processing.js html setup (closed)

Tags: javascript, html, processing.js

Alright. This is one of the first times I've done this so it's probably a simple problem. I'm trying to set up a little program in which I define and create an object in "blobby.js" and I then have the `setup` and `draw` inside a script tag in the html file. I'm trying to do this in processing, which I have referenced, as you will see, in the html as well. My problem is even though the background shows up, I have an error in the console that says `random` is not defined. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PATHOGEN</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="processing.min.js"></script>
        <script src="blobby.js"></script>
        <script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="mycanvas">
            void setup()
            {
                size(600,600);
                PFont fontA = loadFont("sans-serif");
                textFont(fontA, 14);  
            }
            console.log(cells); 
            void draw(){  
              background(225, 1, 1);
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                cells[i].show();
            }
            }
        </script>
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, here is the code in blobby.js:

```
var blobby = function(X, Y, S) {
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
    this.s = S;
};

console.log("Hey, blobby is here!");

blobby.prototype.show = function(){
    //Blobbiness and plasma membrane
    var perlin = 0;
    pushMatrix();
    translate(this.x, this.y);
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke(20, 210, 60, 170);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    beginShape();
    for (var a = 0; a < TWO_PI; a+=0.1){ 
        var d = map(noise(perlin, frameCount/100), 0, 1, this.s-10, this.s);
        var x = sin(a)*d;
        var y = cos(a)*d;
        vertex(x, y);
        perlin+=0.1;
    }

    endShape(CLOSE);
    popMatrix();
};

var cells = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    cells.push(new blobby(random(100, 500), random(100, 500), random(70, 100)));
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your case **random** is a function that you are calling, but it **is not defined** anywhere in that file or in your script tag present in your index.html.
Also I think you are trying to do Math.random to get a random number.
So if you just change from **random** to **Math.random**, your problem will be solved.

Comment: So far as I can tell, the random function is working now, but not it says pushMatrix is not defined. I know [pushMatrix](http://processingjs.org/reference/pushMatrix_/) is a function in processing.js, so I think my problem is perhaps that I have not set up the processing library. Is there anything wrong with how I set up my html?

Comment: Try moving all the javascript code from your index.html into blobby.js.

Comment: Then also this might not work due to cross-origin request error. The only solution is to run the project on a server, or to open the project in forefox or safari where you will not get cross-origin request errors.